# Why is python adding a prefix /home/user to the PYTHONPATH variable I set?

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables, pythonpath

I am using caffe with python on ubuntu 16.04 now, after compiling and installing, I need to add the directory of caffe to the `PYTHONPATH` variable in order that python knows how to find it when importing. But strange things happen here. I added the following line in `~/.bashrc`:

`export PYTHONPATH="~/caffe/python/:$PYTHONPATH"`

No need to mention, I encountered the problem that importing caffe failed, and I tried to find out why. Here is what I did in python:

> `>>>import sys`
>
> `>>>sys.path`
>
> `['','/home/roof/~/caffe/python',…………………]`

Bash or python is adding a prefix `/home/roof/` to the `PYTHONPATH` variable I set, which is unexpected, but why? How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop quoting the tilde, since that interferes with expansion.

```
$ FOO="~" bash -c 'echo $FOO'
~
$ FOO=~ bash -c 'echo $FOO'
/home/XXXXXX
```